# Accessing a sibling property from within a collection

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a collection of items that is populated from LINQ and I have the need to access a sibling item (a date), that will be set from the UI level. Since I do not know the date at the time the data collection is populated, I need a good way to access the date property from each of the items in the collection. Here is my class structure stripped down:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public DateTime MyDate;
    public List<MySite_ReportResult> Items { get; set; }
}
```

To summarize, for each "MySite_ReportResult", I want to be able to access "MyDate". Does anyone have a good suggestion that is a best practice? This collection will eventually be bound to a grid, so I will be creating a partial class and adding an additional property based on what the DateTime value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **UIDateAndReport** class that will wrap a **My_SiteReportResult** and the **Date**.

Code goes as follow:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<My_SiteReportResult> Reports {get;set;}
}
```

public class UIDateAndReport
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public My_SiteReportResult Report { get; set; }
}

TestClass tst = new TestClass();
...
var DatedReports =
        (from r in tst.Reports
         select new UIDateAndReport { Date = tst.Date, Report = r });

You will end up with an IEnumerable<UIDateAndReport> that you can bind to your UI through an ObservableCollection or a CollectionView.

{enjoy}

Comment: I ended up having a lot of other complications with typing and the fact that this class was actually using generics (maybe I shouldn't have simplified it so much) and was used in many places, but your solution was helpful in getting toward my resolution so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Could this help?

```
...

List<DatedReportResult> list = new List<DatedReportResult>();

foreach (var drs in list) {
   drs.ReportDateTime ..
}

...

class DatedReportResult {
   public DateTime ReportDateTime;

   /* Properties of original ReportResult class */
   ....
}
```

Conversely for the UI you could bind the list, use a BindingSource and access the current item's ReportDateTime property in your code.

Hope this helps.

Thanks